# How get only ID from long string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

in the below string, I need your help in order to know how I can get or select only `GUID` (`NVARCHAR(36)`) using a T-SQL query?

```
N'yes#red#A5257199-8B09-44F1-8073-C5D5F02126F9#No#fuchsia#A5A5B2F2-1B87-4B0E-85B6-16A287814574#'
```

Comment: How to find `ID` in that string ?

Comment: yes how i can select only guid (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) from this string ?

Comment: how many GUID is there in one string

Comment: Which one? There appear to be two GUIDS in that string do you need both? could there be more?   So split on the #, look for strings having 4 '-' and are of length 36. and follow GUid patterns./

Comment: @xQbert I need use it with loop for unlimited GUID

Comment: You don't need a loop use `STRING_SPLIT(Col, '#')` and then use a regexp to validate it's a guid like This [isGUID]((http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View8AD536EF-BC0D-427F-9F15-3A1BC663848E.htm)

Comment: i mean that a need to get only GUIDs when this string contains a lot of guids

Comment: Once you have the GUIDs, what do you want to do with them?  And what rules exist for our being able to find them?  Is it ***always*** `<something>#<somethign else>#<guid>#`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you REALLY don't want to use the function as suggested by Prdp (which is honestly the right way to go), you can do something like below

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeString varchar(max))
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'yes#red#A5257199-8B09-44F1-8073-C5D5F02126F9#No#fuchsia#A5A5B2F2-1B87-4B0E-85B6-16A287814574#')

Select A.ID
      ,GUIDs = B.RetVal 
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(A.SomeString,'#','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)

             ) B Where Len(RetVal)=36
```

Returns

```
ID  GUIDs
1   A5257199-8B09-44F1-8073-C5D5F02126F9
1   A5A5B2F2-1B87-4B0E-85B6-16A287814574
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a split string function to split the the data into different rows then check if the row is `unquieidentfier` then use it.

The function is refered from this article [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
(@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover NVARCHAR(4000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

To extract the `GUID`

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(4000)= N'yes#red#A5257199-8B09-44F1-8073-C5D5F02126F9#No#fuchsia#A5A5B2F2-1B87-4B0E-85B6-16A287814574#'

SELECT item
FROM   dbo.[Delimitedsplit8k](@str, '#')
WHERE  Try_cast(item AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) IS NOT NULL
```

In case you are using `SQL SERVER 2016` then you can use `STRING_SPLIT` function instead of `dbo.[Delimitedsplit8k]`

Comment: first of all thank you so much for your cooperation, but is there any other ways to get ids using t-sql (select query?)

Comment: @MohammadAbuSaloum - Then use the query inside the function directly in Select query. It is will look ugly and incase you want to reproduce something similar then again you need to write big chunk of code